# codeigniter : Input multiple insert to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, multiple-insert

I did multiple inserts with different qty. when making a transaction, I accommodate it in a temporary or append table. However, only the last qty is stored

**[this HTML](https://pastebin.com/EC9ewJth)**

MODEL

```
public function simpan_data($data_pickup){
  $this->simpan_pickup($data_pickup);
  $last_key = $this->db->insert_id();
  $tmp = $this->get_temporary();
  foreach($tmp as $t){
  $data_detail = array(
  'id_pickup'       => $last_key,
  'id_barang'       => $t->id_barang,
  'qty_pickup'      => $this->input->post('qty_pickup')
  );
  $this->db->insert('pickup_detail', $data_detail);
}
} 

public function simpan_pickup($data){
$res = $this->db->insert('pickup', $data);
return $res;
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function add_tem_pickup(){
    $idnya                 = $this->input->post('id_barang');
    $cektmp                = $this->M_pickup->cek_temporary($idnya);
    if ($cektmp > 0) {
        $arr=array(
        'sukses'  => false,
        'pesan'   => 'Barang sudah Pickup'
    );
    //alert
    }else{
    $data_insert      = array(
      'jenis'         => 'PICK',
      'id_barang'     => $idnya
    );
    $this->db->insert('tem_pickup', $data_insert);
    $arr = array(
      'sukses' => true,
      'pesan'   => 'berhasil'
    );
    }
      echo json_encode($arr);
    }

public function simpan_pickup(){
    $data = array(
    'kd_pickup'     => $this->input->post('kd_pickup'),
    'id_cs'         => $this->input->post('id_cs')
    );
    $this->M_pickup->simpan_data($data);
    $this->db->delete('tem_pickup', array('jenis' => 'PICK'));
    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message','success');
    redirect('backend/pickup');
}
```

how could this happen ? Please help

[image: IMAGE EXAMPLE]

Comment: Could you show your html form or the `qty_pickup` input form?

Comment: i'm edit a post wait

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EC9ewJth @HastaDhana

Comment: Could you explain more on your problem, there is only one `qty_pickup` input on your form, not multiple like what you've said

Comment: can u speaking indonesia ? I saw your location in Indonesia :D

Comment: bisa, tapi di StackOverflow sepertinya dilarang, masalahnya di bagian manakah?

Comment: saya membuat tabel inputan, dimana setiap button (tambah), data disimpan di tabel temporary/ditampung .. (saat disimpan di tabel temporary .. tiap qty yang saya inputkan sesuai mas)

saya membuat multi insert apabila transaksi selesai maka data di submit dengan nama button simpan

saya mempunyai tabel 

pickup dan pickup detail (ini hanya untuk histori)

saat saya simpan (proses multi insert), qty nya berbeda hanya mengambil qty terahir yg saya inputkan saja mas .


need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a hidden `qty_pickup` input after the ajax calls success (using jquery [after()](https://api.jquery.com/after/)), here I renamed this new input to `qty_pickup_new[]` to differentiate it with the existing `qty_pickup` input :

```
// another js codes here...
//
$(".btnadd").click(function(){ //input append 
        var id_barang                         = $("input[name='id_barang']").val();
        var nama_barang                       = $("input[name='nama_barang']").val();
        var qty_pickup                        = $("input[name='qty_pickup']").val();
        var sisa                              = $("input[name='qty_pickup']").val();
        var harga_jual                        = $("input[name='harga_jual']").val();
        var satuan                            = $("input[name='satuan']").val();
        var kd_pickup                         = $("input[name='kd_pickup']").val();
        // var tgl_pickup                        = $("input[name='tgl_pickup']").val();
        var tipe_dimensi                      = $("input[name='tipe_dimensi']").val();
        var tgl_pickup                        = $("input[name='tgl_pickup']").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>backend/pickup/add_tem_pickup',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                id_barang: id_barang,
                qty_pickup: qty_pickup,
                sisa: qty_pickup,
                harga_jual: harga_jual, 
                kd_pickup: kd_pickup,  
                // tgl_pickup: tgl_pickup, 
                satuan: satuan, 
                tipe_dimensi: tipe_dimensi,
                tgl_pickup: tgl_pickup, 
                },
            error: function() {
            },
            success: function(data) {
            if(data.sukses==false){
            alert(data.pesan);
            }else{
            $('#tbody').append("<tr><td>"+kd_pickup+"</td><td>"+nama_barang+"</td><td>"+qty_pickup+"</td><td>"+harga_jual+"</td><td>"+satuan+"</td><td>"+tipe_dimensi+"</td></tr>"); 
            //  added below codes, set array input with id_barang as the key
            $('[name="harga_jual"]').after('<input type="hidden" name="qty_pickup_new[' + id_barang + ']" value="' + qty_pickup + '">');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then you could use the `qty_pickup_new[]` on the model by using the `id_barang` as the key (as previous javascript codes does) :

```php
public function simpan_data($data_pickup){
    $this->simpan_pickup($data_pickup);
    $last_key = $this->db->insert_id();
    $tmp = $this->get_temporary();
    foreach($tmp as $t){
        $qty_pickup = $this->input->post('qty_pickup_new')[$t->id_barang]; // using id_barang as qty_pickup_new[] key
        $data_detail = array(
            'id_pickup'       => $last_key,
            'id_barang'       => $t->id_barang,
            'qty_pickup'      => !empty($qty_pickup) ? $qty_pickup : '' // sets data as empty if input is empty
        );
        $this->db->insert('pickup_detail', $data_detail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir,

I want to learn a lot, is there a contact that can be contacted, for example telegram?

maybe i can give an incentive someday :)